# Execute .as file as .mc file

Tags: c, cpu-architecture

I have a LC-2K assembler sample code (C language) that takes assembly code(input.as) and converts it to machine code(output.mc).

I need to execute the assembler.c like this..

*input.as -> assembler.c -> output.mc*

I tried **c:\directory of assembler\Assembler.exe< input.as > output.mc**

but it creates a .mc file with error message "error: usage: Assembler.exe < assembly-code-file > < machine-code-file >"

How should I run this assembler program via cmd to create output.mc file ?

Comment: Ignore the angle brackets. Those are usually used to designate what is a single command-line argument.

Comment: Is there any specific cmd command for this? I tried it without angle brackets but it creates empty output file.

Comment: If it's creating an output file, then at least it's getting your output filename properly. You're running (prepending the path to the assembler) `Assembler.exe input.as output.mc`? Are there any diagnostic messages printed?

Comment: I tried c:\program path\Assembler>Assembler.exe input.as output.mc on cmd, but it creates empty file without any diagnostic messages.. Should I use gcc command ?

Comment: Is the angle bracket before `Assembler.exe` a typo, or what you actually ran? Does your `input.as` actually have content that will result in assembled machine code? What are you doing to check that the output file is empty?

Comment: GCC is used to compile your program, your question seems to revolve around using the assembler. You haven't shown much information usable to help you. The main question you have is "How should I run this assembler program via cmd to create output.mc file ?" which has absolutely nothing to do with C.

Comment: What C file? Where in your command is there a C file?

Comment: @Cheatah So I have Assembler.c, Assembler.exe, and input.as files. I used Assembler.exe instead of Assembler.c in cmd command because "c:\directory of assembler\Assembler.c  input.as output.mc" only opens file, not creates output.mc fi